# redefinition of class when I use calib3d.hpp in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am working on ubuntu 16.4 in a C++ project and I'm trying to use a function in opencv2/calib3d.hpp but without any success.

I don't have any problem using cv::Point3d for example, but as soon as I add , I get the following error:

> /usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:69: error:
>   redefinition of ‘class cv::KeyPoint’  class CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE
>   KeyPoint

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "cv hello"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I use " pkg-config --modversion opencv " to have the version of opencv used I get "3.1.0"

My idea is that I have several version of opencv installed and conflicting.
I am thinking that because in the proposition of completion, when I am adding
 #include , I have several equivalent calib3d.hpp propositions.

How can I know if I have multiple version installed ?

Comment: Maybe you should try at https://askubuntu.com/ with this question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is to much effort, but you could specify the OpenCV version with Cmake.

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.2 REQUIRED PATHS "/path/to/OCV3.2/install/dir/")
```

Check this answer from @gabriel-devillers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45752688/10889595